# Where to put "a lot" of data, array / file / somewhere else, in JS on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

This may be a "stupid" question to ask, but I am working with a "a lot" of data for the first time. 
What I want to do: Querying the [World Bank API](http://data.worldbank.org/developers?display=)
Problem: The API is very unflexible when it comes to searching/filtering... I could query every country/indicator for it self, but I would generate a lot of calls. So I wanted to download all informations abourt a country or indicator at once and then sort them on the machine. 
My Question: Where/How to store the data? Can I simply but it into an array, do I have to worry about size? Should I write to a temporary json file ? Or do you have another idea ?

Thanks for your time!

Example:
20 Countries, 15 Indicators

If I would query every country for itself I would generate 20*15 API calls, if I would call ALL countries for 1 indicator it would result in 15 API calls. I would get a lot of "junk" data :/

Comment: There is an wrapper around IndexedDB - [Dexie.js](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js). Consider of using it while it could be faster than connecting to any external database or writing the JSON to a file.

Comment: Personally, if it's not too much data I'd store it in a JSON file and use fs.read and fs.write to process it.

Comment: If you're expecting to need to do this often it may be better to load in the data to a database on your server which you'd set up such that it does have search functionality, then access this database instead. Then every few hours refresh that database with the new data from the world bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the data in RAM in an appropriate data structure (array or object) if the following are true:

1. The data is only needed temporarily (during one particular operation) or can easily be retrieved again if your server restarts.
2. If you have enough available RAM for your node.js process to store the data in RAM.  In a typical server environment, there might be more than a GB of RAM available.  I wouldn't recommend using all of that, but you could easily use 100MB of that for data storage.

Keeping it in RAM will likely make it faster and easier to interact with than storing it on disk.  The data will, obviously, not be persistent across server restarts if it is in RAM.

If the data is needed long term and you only want to fetch it once and then have access to the data over and over again even if your server restarts of if the data is more than hundreds of MBs or if your server environment does not have a lot of RAM, then you will want to write the data to an appropriate database where it will persist and you can query it as needed.

If you don't know how large your data will be, you can write code to temporarily put it in an array/object and observe the memory usage of your node.js process after the data has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing it in a nosql database, since you'll be working with JSON, and querying from there.

mongodb is very 'node friendly' - there's the native driver - https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native
or mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Storing data from an external source you don't control brings with it the complexity of keeping the data in sync if the data happens to change. Without knowing your use case or the API it's hard to make recommendations. For example, are you sure you need the entire data set? Is there a way to filter down the data based on information you already have (user input, etc)?